# Update CustomArrayAdapter after AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I m having a CustomArrayAdapter which I m using to update a a custom ListView.

This is working fine but when I m trying to update the view 
 after getting results in AsyncView onPostExecute using notifyDataSetChanged it is not updating nor it is returning any exceptions.

The code for onCreate -

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] presidents = {"Dwight D. Eisenhower","John F. Kennedy","Lyndon B. Johnson","Richard Nixon","Gerald Ford","Jimmy Carter","Ronald Reagan","George H. W. Bush","Bill Clinton","George W. Bush","Barack Obama"};
    String[] pics = {"5237","5438", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184"};
    private String[] names;
    private String[] pid;   
    ListActivity obj;   
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        obj = this;     
        try {
            adapter =new CustomArrayAdapter(obj, presidents, pics);
            setListAdapter(adapter);            
            new DownloadTextTask().execute("http://nvoids.com/rest/hello/users/");          
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("Listview1", "Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }
```

The AsyncTask's onPostExecute -

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result.substring(1, 10) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
  try 
    {               
        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(result);
         names = new String[jarr.length() -1];
         pid = new String[jarr.length() -1];
         for (int i =0; i< jarr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jarr.get(i).toString());
                names[i] = jObj.getString("value");                 
                pid[i] = jObj.getString("pid");                 
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            adapter =new CustomArrayAdapter(obj, names, pid);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("ListView1", "after getting string: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

By the way the CustomArrayAdapter class if required -

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;    
private final String[] presidents;    
private final String[] imageIds;

 public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity context,String[] presidents, String[] imageIds) {
    super(context, R.layout.lvrowlayout, presidents);
     this.context = context;
     this.presidents = presidents;
     this.imageIds = imageIds;
 }

 @Override    
 public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
     //---print the index of the row to examine---        
     Log.d("Listview1",String.valueOf(position));

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lvrowlayout, null, true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtPresidentName);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    txtTitle.setText(presidents[position]);

    //imageView.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);

    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView)  imageView )
    .execute("http://nvoids.com/dir/image_" + imageIds[position] + ".jpeg");


    return rowView;

 }

 private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Log.d("CustomArrayGetImage Error", urldisplay);
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("CustomArrayGetImage Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }    
 }
```

**EDIT -**

As in the answers passing the parameters also does not work -

```
  try {
        adapter =new CustomArrayAdapter(obj, presidents, pics);         
        setListAdapter(adapter);            
        new DownloadTextTask(adapter).execute( "http://nvoids.com/rest/hello/users/");          
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("Listview1", "Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

In the DownloadAsyncTask -

```
   private class DownloadTextTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    CustomArrayAdapter ca;

    public DownloadTextTask(CustomArrayAdapter ca) {
        this.ca = ca;
    }

 ......

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result.substring(1, 10) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
        try 
        {               
            JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(result);
            names = new String[jarr.length() -1];
            pid = new String[jarr.length() -1];
            for (int i =0; i< jarr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jarr.get(i).toString());
                names[i] = jObj.getString("value");                 
                pid[i] = jObj.getString("pid");
                ca.addAll(names[i] , pid[i]);
            }
            /*
            super.onPostExecute(result);                
            adapter =new CustomArrayAdapter(obj, names, pid);               
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);             
            obj.setListAdapter(adapter);
            */

            ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("ListView1", "after getting string: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, You are creating new object of Custom Adapter in AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()`

Like,

```
adapter =new CustomArrayAdapter(obj, names, pid);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Which is not set to `ListView`. So either write syntax for `setListAdapter()` to ListView in `onPostExecute()` (For this you need ListView reference in AsyncTask) or 
**Use the same object** which you have created in `onCreate()` of Your `ListActivity`, Pass that adapter object in Constructor of AsyncTask and use Object in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I was writing (you were too fast :) ). To complete a bit your answer, you can use the methods add, insert, addAll and/or remove of your adapter to insert the data you got in onPostExecute method.

Comment: with the constructors also it is not responding I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter =new CustomArrayAdapter(obj, names, pid);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[notifyDataSetChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) notify observers to update data.

So in your example you notify **new** adapter to update their data, but you don't attach adapter to your list.

But create each time new adapter - is not a good practise, you have to update data in your adapter (in your case list of presidents) and then call notifyDataSetChange on your existing adapter.

PS [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) already have a list under it and you can call [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29) and don't need to store list of presidents. In your case i think it's better to create

`class PresidentsWrapper {
    String name,
    String photoUrl
 }`

And `create ArrayAdapter<PresidentWrapper>`

In this case you don't need any underlying structures and can do like this:

```
getItem(position);
add(new PresidentWrapper(...));
```